# Scrolling on a type="number" input to change its value: How to stop parent's scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, material-ui, dom-events

I have a form inside an `overflow: auto` container with fixed dimensions. When the form is bigger as the container, the container gets scroll bars. All good. Now one of the inputs inside the form is of `type="number"`. This is convenient because the browser provides the capability of changing its value with the mouse wheel. Awesome.

Now the problem:

#### How can I prevent the container from scrolling when I am changing the value of these inputs using the mouse wheel?

This might seem like a common problem, but I don't find any clean solution out there. **Note** that I don't want to disable scrolling nor the scroll bars to disappear, I just want to stop propagation of the wheel event to the parent container, when captured in that specific type of input, if that makes sense or is possible.

I am using React with JSX syntax and Material-UI components.

Adding an `onWheel={e => e.stopPropagation()}` on the input or trying to intercept the `onWheel` event in the container wasn't working (I was getting a `Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive` error).

[illustration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl8sm.gif)

Comment: Sorry to inform you that this is default browser behaviour. There are ways of stopping the scrolling, but it is not simple. https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3365-prevent-scrolling-in-a-parent-element-using-directives-in-angular-4-4-6.htm could help. It is in Angular, but very well documented.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across this exact problem and managed to fix it using native JS events instead of React's. Here's a simple wrapper around input element:

```
import React, { FC, InputHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

type NumericInputProps = Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'type'>;

const handleWheel = (e: WheelEvent) => e.stopPropagation();

export const NumericInput: FC<NumericInputProps> = (props) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const inputElem = inputRef.current;
    inputElem?.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);

    return () => inputElem?.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel);
  }, []);

  return <input ref={inputRef} type="number" {...props} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, adding this to the container that scrolled worked for me. I don't know why it works, the handler function is empty. If someone could throw some light into this it would be great.

```
const Container = props => {
  const reference = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const reff = reference.current;
    const wheelHandler = () => {}; // Empty handler???
    reff.addEventListener('wheel', wheelHandler);
    return () => reff.removeEventListener('wheel', wheelHandler);
  }, [reference])

  return <Box ref={reference} className={classes.content} {...props} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exactly same problem with the MUI `<TextField>` component.

The suggested answer by @Piotr didn't work for me, because `useEffect` will only execute once before the `inputRef` is bound to the `<input>` element, which means `addEventListener` will never be called.

Along similar lines, I ended up solving this with [callback refs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback). Here is a simple example (I use TypeScript in my project):

```
function NumberControl() {
  const handleWheel = useCallback((e: WheelEvent) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, []);

  const callbackRef = useCallback(
    (inputElement: HTMLInputElement | null) => {
      inputElement?.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
    },
    [handleWheel]
  );

  return <TextField type="number" ref={callbackRef} />;
}
```

A trivial downside of the above code is that we don't have a [cleanup function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters) like that in `useEffect` because [callback refs do not support clean up functions, yet](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/205). However, one can easily implement a hook to mimic the cleanup semantic of `useEffect`. I borrowed [the answer here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15176#issuecomment-512740882) and tweaked it into a typed hook:

```
function useCallbackRef<T, CB extends (() => unknown) | void>(
  rawCallback: (node: T) => CB
) {
  const cleanupRef = useRef<CB | null>(null);
  return useCallback(
    (node: T | null) => {
      if (cleanupRef.current) {
        cleanupRef.current();
        cleanupRef.current = null;
      }
      if (node) {
        cleanupRef.current = rawCallback(node);
      }
    },
    [rawCallback]
  );
}
```

And our example above can be then changed into:

```
function useStopWheelPropagationCallbackRef<
  T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement
>() {
  const handleWheel = useCallback((e: WheelEvent) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, []);
  const callbackRef = useCallbackRef(
    useCallback(
      (htmlElement: T) => {
        htmlElement.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
        return () => {
          htmlElement.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
        };
      },
      [handleWheel]
    )
  );
  return callbackRef;
}

function NumberControl() {
  const callbackRef = useStopWheelPropagationCallbackRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  return <TextField type="number" ref={callbackRef} />;
}
```